# CoreNLP (Arabic) Incorrect Part of Speech Tag

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP POS 3.3.1 with HeidelTime for temporal analysis (unfortunately, there is no SO tag for HeidelTime, so I opened an issue and linked to this post).

I've specifically been working with Arabic and with a BBC Arabic article, I noticed that HeidelTime ignores the number '6', picks up "hour" and understands it to be 1 hour.  HeidelTime then spits out the TIMEX3 tag with value=PT1H.

For example, the following text is what I started with:

قبل 6 ساعة ("before 6 hour", read right to left and is respective of the word order, i.e. "قبل" is "before")

The reason for this SO post is, I ran the same phrase through Stanford's POS Tagger (without HeidelTime) and it detected:

ساعة/NN 6/CD قبل/NN

So, it tagged each of the words, though it detected (قبل) as a noun, when it should (I believe) be a preposition.

Is this an error, or is it because of the grammar in the original phrase as used by BBC?  I don't think the original phrase is grammatically correct, "hour" should have been plural OR (from my understanding) be before the cardinal number at which point, it could have been left as singular.

Even if it is grammatically incorrect, I can't see any situation where the word "before" would be a noun.

**EDIT 1** As a follow-up, I translated the following from English to Arabic and ran it through POS.

> Before the kids went outside, they had to clean their room.
>
> قبل الاطفال ذهب خارج، كان لديهم لتنظيف غرفهم. (transposed)

POS return the following:

> قبل/NN الاطفال/DTNN ذهب/VBD خارج،/NN كان/VBD لديهم/NN لتنظيف/NN غرفهم./NNP

Showing the word for "before" (قبل) as a noun.  It does appear to be an error.

Comment: Machine-learned models have error rates and make mistakes.